# Firefox 124: How to change background color of active tab, in userChrome.css?

Tags: css, firefox

The following code, appended to userChrome.css, no longer works:

```
.tab-background[selected="true"] {
    background-color: #dd9933 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Literally everything I could find online including this site and reddit, recommended this, but to no avail. The active tab is a tiny shade of gray darker than the other tab, and not orange as I defined it here.

I am not a person with visual impairment but even for me it's hard to make out the active tab in a sea of inactive tabs because the color is just off by 5% or so.

Frustrating how Mozilla keeps moving these CSS settings around what what worked a month ago has to be broken the next month for no apparent reason. Anyone have any insights of what the CSS for the day is?

Comment: https://color.firefox.com/ > Advanced colors -> Tab Selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that Firefox is not looking for your `userChrome.css` on startup.

1. Open up a tab and navigate to `about:config` and click `Accept the Risk and Continue`.
2. In the `Search for Preference` box type `userprof`.
3. It should find the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` option. Just click the `toggle` button on the far right to change the setting to `true`.
4. Modify your `userChrome.css` to this:

```css
.tab-background:is([selected], [multiselected]) {
    background-color: #dd9933 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

5. Restart your browser.

**Note**: looking with the Browser Toolbox it would appear that Firefox adds a `selected=""` attribute to the currently selected tab which is why your css selector of `.tab-background[selected="true"]` no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```css
.tab-background[selected] {
    background-color: #dd9933 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe the CSS selector for the active tab(s) has changed with the new Firefox version.

What many don't know is that you can **inspect the browser itself** with the dev tools, just like you would inspect a web page and its DOM; it's called [Browser Toolbox in Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html).

After taking a look at the element in question in the Inspector, you'll be able to see the element itself, its attributes, and the *applied* CSS styles.

In your case, I would *suggest using* the **attribute selector that the Firefox browser itself uses** to style its active tabs (as can be seen in the following screenshot):

```css
.tab-background:is([selected], [multiselected])
```

[image: Firefox Browser Toolbox Inspector]

---

If this still doesn't work, *try* to **debug it yourself** using the Browser Toolbox:

- Is your CSS file loaded and applied at all?
- Is it really overriding Firefox's default applied CSS rule? Check the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your applied CSS selector.